# Cannot install any package in R at Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, r

I have installed R in my Ubuntu (18.04) system and when I try to install a package I receive the following message (for example when trying to install `dplyr` package):

```
> install.packages('dplyr')
Installing package into ‘/home/giwrikas/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning message:
package ‘dplyr’ is not available (for R version 4.0.2)
```

The same error appears with every package. Does anyone know how to solve that ?

It seems that the library is not writable and often appears the following message:

```
Would you like to use a personal library instead?  (y/n) y

Would you like to create a personal library
~/R/pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2
to install packages into?  (y/n) y
```

My R version is 4.0.2. The same R version works fine at windows.Thank you in advance

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy r-base-dev` to the question. This looks strange, as the says that it [needs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/index.html) R ≥3.2. Can you open https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib URL from web-browser?

Comment: Yes I can open the URL in the browser. I run this command but I can not send you the output because has too many characters. And I can not attach a screenshot here. Also it seems that   I can not either send you a personal message because I dont use the premium version. Any ideas ? Thank you in advance

Comment: For long pastes you can use https://pastebin.com/ .

Comment: Ok, I used Pastebin. Now, Can I share this link in order for you to check the message? Does it work?https://pastebin.com/raw/tu1mGdUE

Comment: R version is correct, could you please run `Rscript -e "install.packages('dplyr')"` from terminal and upload results to the pastebin too.

Comment: Hi again, sorry for the latency. Here it is the outcome of this command.  https://pastebin.com/raw/3wyEZeD8

Comment: I suppose that you have some problems with: wget or curl in your system. Please ensure that you have installed all current updates to the system - by running `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` (to get newest dependencies). Then add output of `dpkg -l | grep -E "curl|wget" ; apt-cache policy curl wget ` to the question.

Comment: I did run these two commands and I am attaching the output of the third one: https://pastebin.com/raw/xrzjWvvY

Comment: I have the absolutely same packages versions. Can install any R package. I would recommend the following: 1) open R shell; 2) change default CRAN mirror to the nearest by  `chooseCRANmirror()`  ; 3) retry package installation with `install.packages('dplyr')` .

Comment: I have only installed R and I currently don't have an editor (e.g. like RStudio, in order to do this modification).  I suppose that I have to install one ?

Comment: This is what I get when trying to change CRAN mirror:
> chooseCREANmirror()
Error in chooseCREANmirror() : 
  could not find function "chooseCREANmirror"
> chooseCRANmirror()
Warning: failed to download mirrors file (cannot open URL 'https://cran.r-project.org/CRAN_mirrors.csv'); using local file '/usr/share/R/doc/CRAN_mirrors.csv'
Warning message:
In download.file(url, destfile = f, quiet = TRUE) :
  URL 'https://cran.r-project.org/CRAN_mirrors.csv': status was 'Couldn't resolve proxy name'
>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110166/discussion-between-n0rbert-and-giorgos-marinos).

Answer (score 1):

Are you behind a firewall ? I had to add the proxy to my Renviron.site before proceeding on various servers:

`sudo nano /usr/lib/R/etc/Renviron.site`

```
#add following, edit to your proxy
http_proxy=http://myproxy.com:8080
https_proxy=http://myproxy.com:8080
ftp_proxy=http://myproxy.com:8080
```

Comment: Hi! I just open this file and add these ? -->http_proxy=http://myproxy.com:8080
https_proxy=http://myproxy.com:8080
ftp_proxy=http://myproxy.com:8080 ? If you could share more info about it I would appreciate, because I tried but I don't know if I did the process right, Thanks in advance!

Comment: You didn't mention if you were behind a proxy ? Also myproxy should be your company or university proxy server. (i.e. not myproxy, that is a placeholder )

Answer (score 0):

Try to switch to other mirror using the following procedure:

1. Open terminal and launch `R` shell
2. In `R` shell switch the mirror by `chooseCRANmirror()`  - in opened window choose nearest mirror
3. In `R` shell retry package installation with `install.packages('dplyr')`

Comment: This is what I get when trying to change CRAN mirror: 
> chooseCREANmirror() Error in chooseCREANmirror() : could not find function "chooseCREANmirror" > chooseCRANmirror() Warning: failed to download mirrors file (cannot open URL 'cran.r-project.org/CRAN_mirrors.csv'); using local file '/usr/share/R/doc/CRAN_mirrors.csv' Warning message: In download.file(url, destfile = f, quiet = TRUE) : URL 'cran.r-project.org/CRAN_mirrors.csv': status was 'Couldn't resolve proxy name' > –

Answer (score -1):

The newest version of R that you seem to want can be installed without adding software sources to the default repositories starting in Ubuntu 20.10 which won't be released until November. An earlier version of r-cran-dplyr can be installed right now from the default repositories in 18.04, but it drags in r-base-core 3.4.4 as a dependency. Since you can't have both ideal conditions at that same time, you need to start think clearly about what your priorities are. Do you really need the latest version of dplyr to be installed in not the latest version of Ubuntu, or do you have room to maneuver between the conflicting requirements of different package versions?

In Ubuntu 18.04 and later open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install r-cran-dplyr # installs r-base-core 3.4.4 as a dependency
```

This GNU R package provides a fast, consistent tool for working with data frame like objects, both in memory and out of memory. r-base-core 4.0 won't land in the default Ubuntu repositories until Ubuntu 20.10.

Comment: These packages are usually outdated. An OP uses R 4.0 from third-party repository.