# Cannot install any R packages after installing Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, r

Please are there any hints on why I am not able to install any R packages? I recently installed the Ubuntu 20.04 LTS OS as well as R and R studio. I am however not able to install any packages in R. I have gone through a seemingly related post  such as [Cannot install any R packages on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1255721/cannot-install-any-package-in-r-at-ubuntu-18-04) but the solutions appear not to help in my case. For instance, while trying to install the ggplot2 package, I get reports that various dependencies are not installed, but trying to install any one of them does not work at all. I will be grateful for any suggestions.

I have added here the last of the error statements and R session info after trying to install the ggplot2 package, as well as the outputs when I run the commands `R --version` and apt-cache policy `r-base-dev`:

```
install.packages("ggplot2")

* removing ‘/home/power/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/tibble’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tibble’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘digest’, ‘glue’, ‘isoband’, ‘rlang’, ‘scales’, ‘tibble’ are not available for package ‘ggplot2’
* removing ‘/home/power/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/ggplot2’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ggplot2’ had non-zero exit status

> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.9.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.9.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.1.0 tools_4.1.0 


(base) power@power-SYS-7039A-I:~$ R --version
R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18) -- "Camp Pontanezen"
Copyright (C) 2021 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under the terms of the
GNU General Public License versions 2 or 3.
For more information about these matters see
https://www.gnu.org/licenses/.

(base) power@power-SYS-7039A-I:~$ apt-cache policy r-base-dev
r-base-dev:
  Installed: 4.1.0-1.2004.0
  Candidate: 4.1.0-1.2004.0
  Version table:
 *** 4.1.0-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     4.0.5-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.4-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.3-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.2-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.1-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.0-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     3.6.3-2 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe i386 Packages
(base) power@power-SYS-7039A-I:~$
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add output of `R --version` and `apt-cache policy r-base-dev`.  You are probably missing some development packages for ggplot compilation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to carefully check R console output while it compiles the packages for you.

On fresh 20.04 LTS with [R 4.1](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/), the following actions give success:

```
sudo apt-get install r-base-dev build-essential 
sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libxml2-dev libcairo2-dev libgit2-dev

mkdir -p /home/$USER/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1
R -e "install.packages(c('rlang','ggplot2'), repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/', lib='/home/$USER/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1')"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But running the commands lead to the successful installation of `rlang` and `ggplot2` but I am still neither able to install any other package via RStudio nor on the command line with a command such as `R -e "install.packages(c('devtools'), repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/', lib='/home/$USER/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1')"`

Comment: Please share full log of the above command, upload it to pastebin.